# Swagger UI is not challenging with Basic Auth to the openAPI endpoint

Tags: jax-rs, openapi, swagger-ui

I have a JAX-RS application, and we are using OpenAPI/Swagger to view all the APIs. I want to protect the OpenAPI Endpoint with Basic Auth (URL: http://localhost:8090/openapi). On the first request to the above endpoint, I am setting the response header with 'WWW-Authenticate' and the value 'Basic realm="XXXX"'. This is working fine if I open the URL in the browser PFA chrome.jpg. However, if I open the same URL in Swagger UI, it is not challenging with a username and password and showing 401 page

**Response Header from Swagger**

```
Content-Security-Policy:default-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'none'
Content-Type:application/json
Referrer-Policy:strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000
**WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="XXXX"**
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection:1
Accept:application/json,*/*
```

chrome

[image]

swagger

[image]

Comment: can you share your OpenAPI description?

Comment: Did not get you what do you mean by description.

Comment: Share your OpenAPI document  to see how you defined the security object